# What is this variety of African violet, which has a tubular white with purple flower?

Tags: identification, houseplants, african-violets

I would like to identify this African violet variety.  It has a tubular flower, and is striped white and purple.

[image: []

Comment: Welcome to the site! Did you mean to post two pictures instead of just this one? The question looked like it had two different pictures posted, but when I re-formatted them to get rid of some extraneous numbers, they looked like duplicates. I'd be happy to undo my edit if those were not the same picture!

Comment: they are basically the same picture but one is more in focus so that one would be better to use

Comment: I'm so sorry about that Sharon! Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I put the picture back to the way you had it, and I removed the few extra formatting numbers and brackets! I also added detail to your title. Especially for identification questions, we like as much detail as we can possibly get, both in the title and body of the question. See the tag information for [guidance](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info). Check out our [help] to learn more about us, and please leave a comment if you need help with anything!

Answer (score 4):

This is not an African violet/Saintpaulia,though it is a relative - its Deinostigma tamiana, sometimes called Vietnamese violet. It remains quite small, flowers frequently, and its care regime is the same as that for African violet. Further information here http://everbloominghouseplants.com/primulina-tamiana-vietnamese-violet

Comment: I am grateful for your answer, I found it in a shop in the section with all the other African Violets.

Comment: Lucky you - if I saw one, I'd buy it too...pretty little thing, and makes a change from the more ubiquitous african violets